# How to create PK and Unique Username at Use Table in Entity (Using Code-first)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I want to set as below. 
I am using the latest Entity framework with Code first approach..

```
Public class AppUser
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

But its not working..

Example record as below

[image]

Getting below error message:

> "exceptionmessage": "Column 'UserName' in table 'dbo.ApplicationUser'
>   is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restrict the length of `UserName` property. Use `StringLength` annotation for that.

> If the size of all fixed key columns plus the minimum size of all
>   variable columns specified in the CREATE INDEX statement exceeds 900
>   bytes, the CREATE INDEX statement fails.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your entity

```
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[StringLength(50)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

**StringLength(50)** sets the size for the column to 50 chars. Without it the column created by code first is of type NVARCHAR(MAX) and EF cannot create an index on this kind of columns